Error during BER decoding when opening PDF in Acobat Reader
So we banging our head against the wall with this problem.
See example:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13Ydz70FtOFO8CtUR5u74Ej-7k1gIsnUX/view?usp=sharing
Above document is signed using an external provider (sha256WithRSA) . When the document is opened in A.reader you get the message
At least one signature is invalid
and when clicking on the visible signature (last page your get a pop-up with the message:
Error during BER decoding
We parsed the /Contents of the /Sig object ( in the PDF 34 0 obj) as a ASN1Sequence object (Java) en  checked it is a valid PKCS7 signed data object (it is). When validating the signature it fails (using a Java verifier program) but we don't know why. Below the contents of the /Contents (PKCS7 object) for your convenience:
ASN1Sequence [
  Element 0: 1
  Element 1: [[[[2.5.4.6, EE]], [[2.5.4.10, AS Sertifitseerimiskeskus]], [[2.5.4.97, NTREE-10747013]], [[2.5.4.3, TEST of EID-SK 2016]]], 49055107554612652537246105176508960687]
  Element 2: [2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1, NULL]
  Element 3: [CONTEXT 0][[1.2.840.113549.1.9.3, [1.2.840.113549.1.7.1]], [1.2.840.113549.1.9.5, [241101172455Z]], [1.2.840.113549.1.9.4, [#8eb3dcf8e0754f9375b4e3c502bf5cb4b0540bfff399c29ea6394138e6dd2ed0]], [1.2.840.113549.1.9.16.2.47, [[[[#40526c34d739c7f78b36f04432e9a4067c376e93c95fbe005f7c1aa58fca6cbd]]]]]]
  Element 4: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.11, NULL]
  Element 5: #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
]

Any suggestions ? Thx a lot!

I'm currently on a smart phone only and couldn't check the file, so: have you verified that the BytesRange correctly has the Contents value (the PKCS#7 signature container) as gap?

Hi mkl, thx for your response. Yes, the ByteRange is correct.

Ok. I'll look into this next week.

Hm, I'n not sure why it fails but when checking the PDF, OpenSSL fails the verification with error number 26 "unsuitable certificate purpose". pyHanko and pdfsig also judge the signature invalid. Maybe it is something similar to https://github.com/MatthiasValvekens/pyHanko/discussions/318 (but I haven't look that deep into the signed data object.

Are you sure the certificate matches the private key used for signing? When I decrypt the enclosed signature value using the public key of the alleged signer certificate, I get something that is not a PKCS#1 DigestInfo object at all. This often means that there is a key mismatch.

That being said, you mention that both Adobe Acrobat and a Java verifier program consider your signature invalid. Do you have any reason to believe that it should be valid? Do you have any validator reporting that the signature is valid?

HI gettalong, mkl. Thx for your valuable feedback. The problem is that we don't know why it is invalid. In the PDF there are 2 certs (ENDcert and CACert) and the Java verifier uses the ENDcert to do the signature verification (but if fails). So we start to believe we get the wrong ENDcert from our external service provider and the digest is signed with another ENDcert !? We contact back our provider of and recheck everything. Keep you posted.

"So we start to believe we get the wrong ENDcert from our external service provider and the digest is signed with another ENDcert !?" - That's exactly what I assume and meant by "key mismatch".

@mkl : The provider confirmed there is a Auth cert and a Sign cert and we imported the Auth cert in the PDF. So solved. Thx for your valuable input!

"The provider confirmed ..." - great! Shall I create an answer from our comments or do you want to?

@mkl: Yes feel free to create and answer, I'll afterwards accept it as the correct answer.

Summarizing the discussion in the comments to the question.
A BER decoding issue can occur because of an error in the CMS/PKCS#7 signature container structure, and that's where one usually looks first. But that structure was ok in the case at hand. Alternatively, a BER decoding issue can occur when checking the contained signature value: RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 signatures essentially are RSA encrypted BER encoded DigestInfo structures containing a hash algorithm identifier and a hash value.
Thus, I decrypted the enclosed signature value using the public key of the alleged signer certificate. As result I got something that is not a BER encoded ASN.1 structure at all, let alone a PKCS#1 DigestInfo object, nor does it match the alternative RSASSA-PSS signing scheme format. So this most likely is why Adobe Acrobat reports "Error during BER decoding"
This kind of error often means that there is a key mismatch: The signature has not been created with the private key matching the public key in the alleged signer certificate but instead some other key.
Indeed, in this case it turned out that

there is a Auth cert and a Sign cert and we imported the Auth cert in the PDF.

